# Laravel Homestead remove host only adapter

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead

in my laravel Homestead project i need to change the Host Only virtual box adapter to Bridged Network adapter.

I always end up having 3 Adapters: 1 NAT, 1 Host Only and 1 Bridged Networking.

What i want to achieve is that i have only one Bridged Networking adapter.

I've been searching since two days to find a solution but still havent been able to solve this. 
What I've been doing is, that ive been debugging through the homestead.rb script they are distributing and trying to find the spots i need to edit. What also came in my mind that those two adapters might be the default virtualboxes. 
But i should be able to at least deactivate them somehow in the Homestead.yml

Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to remove the host only adapter.

1) What you want to do is set your settings["networks"] = nil.

2) Then you need to remove line 20-32 so everything that has to do with networking. Be aware that this will disable the  networks feature from your homestead.yml.

3) You need to add this config to your ruby script: config.vm.network :public_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10"

After this you have two adapters available: 1 NAT and 1 Bridged